# Unable to concat var value to inner html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a dialog with a variable value appended to the innerHTML but what I have so far does not seem to work.

```
  var srcValue = "";

  srcValue = testValue;  //Some other function in my code sets the value for srcValue 

  var pathNotFound = new Coral.Dialog().set({
    id: 'pathNotFound',
    variant: 'error',
    header: {
      innerHTML: 'No match found'
    },
    content: {
      innerHTML: srcValue + ' does not exist in the source path.'
    }
  });
```

The dialog's content section displays -> " does not exist in the source path."

instead of -> "testValue does not exist in the source path."

I tried

```
     content: {
      innerHTML: String(srcValue) + ' does not exist in the source path.'
    }
```

which did not work either.

At the same time if I use the same code with the following it works;

var srcValue = "testValue";

Any help with figuring out how to get this to work is greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably your variable `testValue` equals `''` or similar value.

Comment: I hope this link can help you find a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296184/unable-to-concat-var-value-to-inner-html
thanks

Answer (score 0):

console.log() srcValue and let us know what it outputs. The comment above is probably correct. It’s not returning a value. Post that function as well.